# Clarification: Which image (downloaded from adobe xd => It gave 6 different size folders) needs to be added in drawable folder in my android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

Clarification: Which image (downloaded from adobe xd ==> It gave 6 different size drawable folders) needs to be added to drawable folder in my android.

Here I have added drawable-hdpi folder image. But it looks blurred in my app.

Shall I need to add all the different sizes in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [google documents](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).